# Check if correct WordPress post password was entered *only* on Password Protected pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, password-protection

I would like to set a custom field to be hidden, **only** if a user has not entered the correct password.

[`post_password_required()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/) returns `false` if the password has been entered, as well as if there's no password set in the first place.

Is there a way to check if:

1. The post is password protected in the first place
2. The correct password has been entered.

I only want this to occur on pages that are password protected.

Answer (score 4):

You can just make sure that `post_password` exists on the [`$post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object, it will return an empty string if not:

```
if( $post->post_password && !post_password_required() ){
    // Post Password is actually defined in the first place,
    // and `post_password_required()` is returning true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it should work, but my field is remaining hidden after the password has been entered.

Comment: Oh my apologies I had it turned around. Just add a `!`  before the `post_password_required()`. This will check that a password is set on the post, but it's been entered correctly

Comment: This didn't work. I noticed in your rewrite of my question that there was a mistake: post_password_required() returns TRUE if the password has been entered, as well as if there's no password set in the first place, not false. With that in mind, the ! statement you provided returns false after the correct password has been entered, keeping my field hidden.

Comment: If you look at the docs for [`post_password_required()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/), it indicates it returns `false` if "[...] the correct password cookie is present.". It should return true if the post is password protected *and* the password has _not_ been entered. I'd wager you have another issue going on. Can you please update your post with the relevant code?